# Access Docker container on Private IP

Tags: docker, sonarqube, docker-network, azure-vm

I have created a sonarqube docker container in Azure Linux however, I am unable to access it. The Azure Linux VM doesn't have a public IP. It only has a Private IP address.

Anyways, can I access the container on Private IP?

```
 # docker run -d --name sonarqube -p 1.1.1.1:9000:9000 sonarqube:lts
25c34ffb9775a4bd7761d1de1583d4d187f6ce9be6e5db3a419afd1f05806523
HSTSCMN20356:/opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch/config # docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                           NAMES
25c34ffb9775        sonarqube:lts       "./bin/run.sh"      6 seconds ago       Up 4 seconds        1.1.1.1:9000->9000/tcp   sonarqube
:/opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch/config #
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the container on the private address from any machine within the network (like another VM on the same network). You need to have a public IP address to access it over the internet from your PC or you need to connect your PC to the private network using a VPN.

Make sure that sonarqube is not bound to loopback IP (127.x.x.x).

PS: 1.1.1.1 doesn't seem to be a correct internal IP. Are you sure that's your internal IP address?

Comment: 1.1.1.1 is only for reference, how can i check sonarqube is bound to loopback ip

Comment: @SatyamPandey : It shouldn't be by default.